Mockito when().thenThrow() method not working for JPARepository.findAll method that uses Specification and Pageable
This is my first time asking for help on stack overflow so please forgive me if my problem is not clear enough.
I am using spring-data-jpa version 3.2.4 and Mockito version 5.7.0. I have a test that is not working and I'm not sure why. Important to note that I am actually upgrading my spring boot version. It used to use spring-data-jpa version 2.7.18 and Mockito 4.5.1 before I upgraded. And, before upgrade, this exact code did work. So I'm thinking maybe something has changed which causes it to no longer work?
The following is the code within my class, CarServiceTest.java:
@Test
class CarServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    CarService carService;

    @SpyBean
    CarRepository repository;

    @Mock
    Pageable pageable;

    @Mock
    Specification specification;

    @Mock
    CarParams params;

    @Test
    void shouldThrowError() {

        CarParams params = CarParams.builder().manufacturer("Toyota").build();
        when(repository.findAll(specification, pageable)).thenThrow(new     RuntimeException("exception"));

        assertThrows(RuntimeException.class, () -> carService.getCars(params, pageable));
    }

}

CarParams is a class that contains parameters about the car that is used in the service. The following is the method getCars() that is being called in the above assertThrows call:
public PagedCarResponse getCars(CarParams params, Pageable pageable) {

    Page<Car> cars = Try.of( () -> repository.findAll(where CarSpecifications.manufacturerEquals(params.getManufacturer())), pageable)).getOrElseThrow(exception -> new RuntimeException(exception)

}

CarSpecifications is a custom class that just provides static methods for specifications.
Previously, with the older version of spring data jpa and mockito, this test passed. Now, after upgrading, it does not throw the exception and says an Exception is expected but none was thrown, and I'm not sure why this is.
I've tried searching online for the answers and looking through documentation but I've been unsuccessful. I've also tried doing things like changing Repository to an @Mock and then doing
when(repository.findAll(any(Specification.class), any(Pageable.class)).thenThrow(new     RuntimeException("exception"));

But this didn't work either.
I'm hoping somebody knows something I've missed. Thank you.

I'm surprised that it worked at all. Your mockito expression won't match what is eventually being called, you are writing an expectation with a mocked Specification and Pageable. In this case as a new CarSpecification is being created. So your when doesn't match. Instead of using @SpyBean use @MockBean and use any(Specification). If you replace @SpyBean with @Mock it won't be injected into the service and you are operating on different instances (again not matching the when).

In addition to what I wrote above, what is @ComponentTest that isn't a regular Spring Boot annotation. Or is this some made up psuedo code?

Thanks so much, this worked for me! Just changed SpyBean to MockBean and used any(Specification.class) and any(Pageable.class). Also yes the ComponentTest was just made up pseudocode.
